# Php session update after 30 seconds AFK

Tags: php, session, server, google-kubernetes-engine

i have this strange bug on my code.

The php session of my code expire after 30 seconds if AFK, i tried a few tests to watch how the bug was working: (every test was made cleaning the session every time of course)

1. Open the page and inspector to watch the PHPSESSID, don't click
   anything for 35 seconds, so i refresh the page and the token
   PHPSESSID has changed.
2. Open the page and inspector to watch the PHPSESSID, don't click
   anything for 25 seconds, so i refresh the page and the token
   PHPSESSID hasn't changed.
3. if i browse through the various pages of my code the PHPSESSID
   doesn't change unless i wait 30 seconds to change page.

Right know i don't know how to approach this.

Do you coders think this is a **server issue** or a **code issue**?

Thx

Comment: Are you doing anything in code to regenerate the session id? `session_regenerate_id` for example?

Comment: Hi @IanBrindley , in my code i don't think i am regenerating the id but i am using also a SDK that i didn't write, so i don't know exactly.  But even if there is something in the code that regenerate the id, why should do it after 30 seconds and not on page load? Thx

Comment: What is your hosting situation? Is it a shared environment?

Comment: the hosting is a GKE shared environment

Answer (score 0):

Update,

the problem was related to the hosting environment(thx [@Ian Brindley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1698723/ian-brindley)). 
I resolved it using Redis to store the sessionID

Bye

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).